# Why are some letters disappearing in textblocks?

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application that is installed on several hundred machines.  These machines theoretically have the same hardware, and the same base drive, copied for each of them.  On one machine, certain letters do not print to the screen.  As an example, a login dialog says:

```
 s r ID
P sswor
```

Where it should say

```
User ID
Password
```

The keyboard UserControl I am using on the same screen shows the lowercase a on the button, but is missing various other letters.  Edit: This keyboard is using a different font, Segoe UI.  Login textblocks above use Arial.

Any thoughts on why these letters might be disappearing?

Edits: Happens with two different fonts.  Image snippet can be seen here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lobvlogg80bs628/Login%20screen.jpg

Comment: bad video driver?  we'll need a lot more info probably to be of any help.  screenshot?

Comment: Seems like more of a hardware/system issue to me. You've effectively triaged your software, so I doubt that it is causing the issue.

Comment: Image is linked above now.

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting one. Do these elements have anything funky going on with animations/texthintingmodes or anything like that? Does it work fine with other standard fonts and just shows the issue with specific ones you mention? Hate to be that nerdy, but that's kind of a cool little bug you've got there. ;)

Comment: How is the text for these controls being binded?  Does the same behaviour happen if you use the Label control?

Comment: Chris, some of the elements are straight assignments in the XAML, no binding.  `<TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Margin="215,265,609,464" Foreground="Black"  FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  FontFamily="Arial" Width="200">User ID</TextBlock>` is an example.  Garry, this is on one machine in production, and we cannot reproduce it in house.  Swapping to a label is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Have you deleted the app and re-installed?   It could just be bad install.  I would say video card or driver but if you are not seeing other videos problems you have to look at the software.  If it is running fine on a hundred other machines then you have to look at the install.

Comment: Ya if it's only one machine I'd go with Blam's comment. Or at least del/re-install the font in question.

Comment: They're going to try a fresh install, but I'd really like to understand the problem, if possible.  I'm clarifying with the field guys now if the same letters are always missing after reboots or screen reloads.

Comment: More information - Using these two fonts in wordpad showed no issues with rendering on the same machine.  Additionally, this problem has been seen on a small number of other machines in rare occasions in the past.

Comment: What version of .net by chance?

Comment: Target Framework: .NET Framework 4